# WordPress Themes Disappearing

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

I have a WP multi-site running on RunCloud/digital ocean. I've attempted four or five custom themes, but each one would disappear from my theme menu after an hour or two.

Today I've attempted child themes with the same result. This is what is in my twentytwenty-child/style.css:

```
/*Theme Name: level up child                                             
*Description: child theme of 2020                            
*Template: twentytwenty                               
*/                                               
@import url("../twentytwenty/style.css");
```

But as soon as I created a header.php (simply copying the parent header into the child folder) my child theme disappeared. I've since added a functions.php file into the child's folder and with the following...

```
function twentytwenty_child_enqueue_styles() {   
   // Parent theme style handle              
   $parent_style = 'twentytwenty-style';         

    // Enqueue parent and child theme style.css.          
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );   
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',  
 array($parent_style), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));     
};     
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwenty_child_enqueue_styles' );
```

...as per [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), renamed the folder name twice (back to the original name), and no luck. The child theme will not appear in the admin menu.

The child folder (twentytwenty-child/) only has style.css, functions.php, and header.php. All available themes, including twentytwenty, are enabled on multi-site network.

Am I missing something obvious? I'm new to WP theme creation, forgive my ignorance. Thanks!

Comment: Are the files actually reverting to their previous state on your server? I don't know about this particular configuration, but some modern cloud providers don't provide persistent filesystems.

Comment: Do you mean my child files? They are definitely persistent, I just checked and they have not reverted. I'm using DigitalOcean's access console shell.

Comment: /*Theme Name: level up child                                             
*Description: child theme of 2020                            
*Template: twentytwenty                               
*/                                               
@import url("../twentytwenty/style.css");

Comment: comment start with /*

Comment: thanks lakshman, but it is /* in the actual file and not */. I must have done that when creating the comment.

Comment: You shouldn't need the @import if you are using the function - can you try removing that. Also you shouldn't have that semi-colon after the "}" at the end of your function.
In your comment each line should not have a " * ". Move all the text below the /* and above the */ and remove the addition asterisks.
 Another note (this doesn't effect functionality) - the add_action should come before the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I figured it out. [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris) was on to something about it being caused by RunCloud. I 'chown'ed the new child folder and files to runcloud:runcloud (matching the existing theme folders and files ownership) and they reappeared!

As a confirmation, I also ran 'chown root:root' on a working theme folder (twentynineteen). That folder quickly disappeared from the wp-admin menu.

The permissions of default theme folders and my own created child theme were identical. So RunCloud must require ownership of WordPress files in order to read them.